# Memory Leak When Using jQuery .Get API and setTimeout

Tags: jquery, ajax, coldfusion

I am using jQuery 1.4.4 and use the .get API to check to see if I need to refresh data on a page or not. The problem is that there is a memory leak somewhere in the snippet below that I cannot seem to find. You will notice that I do a lot of potentially useless things here like deleting and add back the timer all in an effort to figure out what is going on. I assumed that doing the .load was causing the problem, but at this point, the .load doesn't occur very frequently at all, only when the data from .get returns "true", which is very fairly infrequent and doesn't coincide with the memory leaking I see using windows task manager. One thing to note is that this does not leak at all using Firefox, seems to be IE specific.  I am using IE 8 but don't think that matters much.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    function CheckAlerts() {
    //Must tell Ajax not to cache results
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    $.get("AjaxDataCheck/CheckForDataRefresh.cfm", { datacheck: "MyAlerts"},
      function(data) {
       if (data.indexOf("true") >= 0) {
         $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
         $('#responsecontainer').load('alertchecking_Inner.cfm');
         //Clearing the timer and recreating may force gargage collection.
         clearTimeout(CheckAlertsTimer);
         delete CheckAlertsTimer;
         CheckAlertsTimer = setTimeout(CheckAlerts,2000);
       }
       else
       {
         //Clearing the timer and recreating may force gargage collection.
         clearTimeout(CheckAlertsTimer);
         delete CheckAlertsTimer;
         CheckAlertsTimer = setTimeout(CheckAlerts,2000);
       }
      });
      CheckAlertsTimer = setTimeout(CheckAlerts,2000);
   };
   CheckAlerts()
});
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: This a client-side or server-side leak (i.e. browser or JVM process)?

Comment: I am not sure you have got a memory leak.  What is happening to make you think this is the case.  Have you got any http tool to check out the communications between your browser and the server.  If not I would recommend something like fiddler tool.  A quick search on google will get you the link to the download (it's free).  I don't know if your comments regarding garbage collection make any sense either.  javascript executes in the browser and as far as I am aware this is not a managed environment with a garbage collector

Comment: orangepips, this is a client side leak.  Server appears to be fine.  iexplore.exe just keeps eating more and more memory.

Comment: Andrew, I believe it is a leak due to memory growing in IE.  It never seems to recover the memory it loses when I navigate away from the page in question, but it does stop growing.  Not sure on the garbage collection.  I was just attempting to remove any objects that may be 'building up" and causing the problem.  One other thing to note is that each time .get is called, I see another page in my IE cache that has a unique number appended to the URL. ex:  ?_399929392&datacheck-MyAlerts.  I am familiar with fiddler and will give it a shot.

Comment: Can you provide some example responses' data so others can try to produce the same problem?

Comment: orangepips, the response from the .get is either "true" or "false".  I query the database in the checkfordatarefresh.cfm page and output "true" if a refresh is needed or "false" if it is not.  I had to use indexOf when parsing the return value(data) because a couple of erroneous line feed characters are returned from the Ajax call.(/n)

Comment: @Jeremy: what are example response(s) from `alertchecking_Inner.cfm`?

Comment: Where does CheckAlertsTimer get declared?  I don't see anywhere in your code where you do a simple 'var CheckAlertsTimer;'  Is it meant to be a local variable to your CheckAlerts() function, or is it meant to be a global variable (which is what it appears to be right now)?

Comment: @duncan: think this has to be global to allow for it's clearing and deletion.

Comment: The unique number is the cache-busting mechanism. The `delete` keyword won't be doing what you think in this context. If you think that variable is leading to a leak, try assigning it to `null`: `CheckAlertsTimer = null;`. More about `delete`: http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/

Answer (score 1):

This occurs as the load() function has an issue releasing dom elements. This is specific to IE, and a workaround is

```
document.getElementById("responsecontainer").innerHTML = $('#responsecontainer').load('alertchecking_Inner.cfm');
```

as reported at http://forum.jquery.com/topic/memory-leaks-with-ajax-calls.

Comment: is this true of $.get() as well?