# jQuery $.get() different page every 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display a webpage that contains some visual data on a monitor using a Raspberry Pi that will run 24/7. The webpage has a div layer (say its #div) and I want it to loop through a few web pages every 5 seconds. Each page only has a simple bar chart made with Google Charts.

Everything looks like it's working great, however I think the code creates a memory leak. After a few hours, the web browser (chromium) will crash and say not enough memory.

If anyone can take a look at my code and help me improve it, I'd be very appreciative.

This is the code I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function updateChart1() {
        $.get("chart1.php", function(data) {
        $("#div").html(data);
        window.setTimeout(updateChart2, 5000);
        });
    }
    function updateChart2() {
        $.get("chart2.php", function(data) {
        $("#div").html(data);
        window.setTimeout(updateChart3, 5000);
        });
    }
    function updateChart3() {
        $.get("chart3.php", function(data) {
        $("#div").html(data);
        window.setTimeout(updateChart4, 5000);
        });
    }
    function updateChart4() {
        $.get("chart4.php", function(data) {
        $("#div").html(data);
        window.setTimeout(updateChart1, 5000);
        });
    }
    $(document).ready(updateChart1);
</script>
```

Comment: BTW, you should look after *code reusability* indeed.

Comment: If you use something like a meta timeout you wont run into any memory issues. http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H76.html

Comment: @asawyer The first thing that comes to my mind was that, but how to reload only the content of the div ?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown That's likely part of what's causing the memory leak. Reloading the whole page would solve that. I'd suggest using a much larger delay (30 seconds, maybe even a minute) and just reloading the page.

Comment: You could try to use setInterval instead, along with a flag if new content is ready or not. In this scenario setInterval would only be triggered once, thus I believe this might run better.

Comment: @KevinB yeah, I got it. It's really nice but if, in some cases that page just can't be entirely reloaded. It must be a way.

Comment: Are you really setting the html for same element in each updateChart method?

Comment: Look [this thread](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/memory-leaks-with-ajax-calls) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4763160/1267304).

Comment: Hmm... You're loading a new chart, every 5 seconds. that's one new image every 5 seconds, or, 12/min, 720 per hour, does the browser cache clear out images that were loaded during the same request, or does it just keep piling on?

Comment: @Kevin It depends on the server http headers for the images.

Comment: Ah. the chart itself appears to actually be an iframe containing svg now. Cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you can use an `<iframe>` instead of that div. If that's the case, this is what you'd have:

html:

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="" />
```

js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tm = null;
    function updateChart1() {
        $("#iframe").attr("src", "chart1.php");
        if(tm) clearTimeout(tm);
        tm = window.setTimeout(updateChart2, 5000);
    }
    function updateChart2() {
        $("#iframe").attr("src", "chart2.php");
        if(tm) clearTimeout(tm);
        tm = window.setTimeout(updateChart3, 5000);
    }
    function updateChart3() {
        $("#iframe").attr("src", "chart3.php");
        if(tm) clearTimeout(tm);
        tm = window.setTimeout(updateChart4, 5000);
    }
    function updateChart4() {
        $("#iframe").attr("src", "chart4.php");
        if(tm) clearTimeout(tm);
        tm = window.setTimeout(updateChart1, 5000);
    }        
    $(document).ready(updateChart1);
</script>
```

(The code could be refactored to be reused as others say, but that doesn't affect performance, so It doesn't make sense for the problem).

This way the iframe will have its own memory handling and you won't polute your main page memory, the iframe will fresh reload each time but it won't affect your main page UI with a full reload.

Just in case, I'm clearing the timeouts, but the main improvement is the iframe.

Cheers, from La Paz, Bolivia

Comment: Thank you Edgar, this is a nice solution. I still prefer no iframes, but if this is the only way to stop the memory leak, then I will use iframes.